# What is the string value for type command for an addeventlistener command?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, event-handling, dom-events

Basically for `element.addEventListener()`, what is the type name of a keyboard type event?

For example:

```
somelement.addEventListener( <typename>, somefunction, false );
```

What is the value for `<typename>` for a keyboard type event?  I'm basically building an AJAX based search box that will display results/suggestions as the user types in the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually the event name (as defined as inline html) without the word on.

Here's a reference to them all:
http://javascript.gakaa.com/c/events.aspx

Edit: Not all HTML elements can use the same events. For example, a div can't have a "load" listener.
EX: element.addEventListener("mousedown", doSomething, true);

Key events include:
"keydown"
"keyup"
"keypress"

You can get the keycode via e.getKeyCode();
The window object should be the object listening for keyEvents.

Comment: honestly amazing response time and info.  thank you and god bless you.

Comment: quick question tho, can an input element listen to keyevents? if not, how do i go about it?

Comment: Yep, it can. inputElement.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){onKeyDown(e)}, true); would work, where inputElement is the element, and onKeyDown is a function you defined. The e argument can be used to get the key code.

Comment: hmm interesting, why doesn't "keypressed" work? i tried it but it didn't seem to work...

Comment: Sorry, this should work: element.addEventListener("keypress", function(){alert("hi")}, true);